# Is "to boil down" formal enough to be used in scientific writing?

Tags: formality, phrasal-verbs, writing-style, register, figurative

The [phrase](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/boil_1)

> to boil down to something

can be found in most dictionaries. However, to me, it sounds colloquial to write

> Finding an exact solution to Eq. 1 boils down to ...

A real-life example can be found [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.3586v2), and many more [here](http://search.arxiv.org:8081/?query=%22boils%20down%20to%22&in=). Interestingly, many of the examples are by non-native speakers.

Is it good style to use this phrase in formal writing?

(I am prepared to hear that if people use it, then it is OK.)

Comment: It's fine in conversation, and in emails, but I would discourage its use in formal papers. Kris's answer is the correct one, although it would have been more helpful if he/she had suggested a suitable alternative.

Comment: I don't agree that it should *never* be used -- ISTM there are contexts where this idiom captures something that a more strict formulation omits -- but some formal alternatives might be (depending on context): **is equivalent to**, **reduces to**, **may be approximated by**, **requires**...

Comment: If you're writing a formal article on chemistry, it could probably be interpreted in all sorts of ways... :-)

Comment: No. It's not good style in formal scientific writing.

Comment: If, for example, you were writing for a scientific journal that would be read by both native and non-native speakers, it would be best to avoid using phrasal verbs, cliches, idioms, acronyms  etc.  many non-native speakers will find themselves puzzling over their meaning and might interpret them in a literal way (see rand al'thor's comment). If the readership consists solely of native English speakers, or it is restricted to a small group, you can use this type of phrasal verb but it might still come across as being "colloquial" and unprofessional sounding (IMNSHO).

Comment: Scientific writing and formal writing use different guidelines.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As has been suggested in other answers, it is not very suitable in formal writing. Here are some alternatives you might consider:

- amount to
- be reduced to
- be a matter of
- be in essence

Comment: +1 for *reduce* as in *and thus the above definition reduces to the following:*

Comment: I think that *it is suitable* for formal writings. *However*, these phrases listed above are definitely *preferred*.

Answer (score 12):

*[Boil down to](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/boil-down-to-sth)* is not informal. It can be used even in formal writing.

Comment: I've seen it several times in very well written mathematical papers.

Answer (score 6):

The aim of scientific writing is to be clear and precise, not to be pretentious or highfalutin. There is absolutely nothing wrong with using the phrase *to boil down*. You could also say *distill*; it makes no difference.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Do not use cliches, catch-phrases, metaphors, slang words … in formal writing.

Comment: and avoid where possible phrasal verbs.

Comment: I don't agree. I think I've seen this term in scientific articles. Though I am not native speaker, I agree with the opinion of Jasper.

Comment: @Tomas The phrase is certainly used, but the question is if it is good style to do so.

Comment: As I am not your downvoter, I can comment freely. This is terse advice with little explanation and no alternative provided. But I wonder: which of “cliché, catch-phrase, metaphor, or slang word” do you consider this use of the phrasal verb *boil down*? The OED doesn’t say it is any of those things. Rather, it gives the primary sense of ***boil down*** as “to lessen the bulk of (anything) by boiling”, along with a figurative sense of “to condense, epitomize”. I presume you object to the common figurative sense used here as inappropriate to the register of a formal research paper. Please expand.

Comment: @tchrist I would have considered it to be a phrasal verb, the use of which in scientific writing was discouraged by Mari-Lou A.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I sense that you are right, that phrasal verbs are not common in formal writing or speech, but can you give an actual reason why they are to be avoided?

Comment: @Mitch I explained in the comments above. Basically, non-native speakers have difficulty in deciphering many phrasal verbs. A writer risks alienating his readership if he's not careful or absolute certain that the PV is universally understood e.g. take off (common) vs hang about (confusing)

Comment: @Mari-LouA That's a reasonable explanation. phrasal verbs tend to be very non-literal and vague and shifting multiple meanings. But maybe they should be taught special in ESL.

Comment: But there are taught, they have to be. The problem is that there are so many, and the same phrasal verb can carry multiple meanings. E.g. *take off*; *take on*; *take up* etc. they all have more than one meaning.

Answer (score 3):

@PainfulEnglish, your question prompted me to research for both of us and anyone else interested. I am writing a science fiction novel and want the science sections as realistic and believable as possible. Following are links to three short papers I found valuable.

"Introduction to Journal-Style Scientific Writing"

- Do not use colloquial speech, slang, or "childish" words or phrases.
- Do not use contractions: for example, "don't" must be "do not" and "isn't" must be "is not" etc.

http://abacus.bates.edu/~ganderso/biology/resources/writing/HTWgeneral.html

"Guidelines for Writing a Scientific Paper" 
http://www.sci.sdsu.edu/~smaloy/MicrobialGenetics/topics/scientific-writing.pdf

"Word Usage in Scientific Writing"
http://www.ag.iastate.edu/aginfo/word_usage.php

Answer (score 2):

If there is something about the metaphor of *boiling down* that is appropriate, you might consider the more scientific term **distills**.

On the other hand, you might want to be more direct and less metaphorical if you are writing a scientific paper.

Answer (score 2):

It might be better in a verbal presentation, where it's more personal and no matter how formal the environment is, an expression like that is good because of its simplicity.